# Meeting probability with known schedule for each individual

Tags: probability

I have some trouble designing the probability of two people meeting at the same time with the hypothesis that we are aware of their schedule.

For simplicity, suppose A's daily schedule can be divided into 4 blocks of 6 hours (Here, it means that A is active from 00:00 to 12:00, then to 18:00 to 24:00):
$$
1, 1, 0, 1
$$
Likewise, B's daily schedule can be divded this way:
$$
1, 0, 0, 1
$$

What is the correct way to compute the probability that A and B are active at the same time?

This is my reasoning:

A is active three times. B is active once. A and B can only meets twice (fromm 00:00 to 6:00 and 18:00 to 24:00)
Therefore,
$$
P(A,B) = \frac{\#(A \cap B = 1 )^2}{\#(A=1) × \#(B=1)} = \frac{2^2}{3 × 2} = \frac{4}{6}.
$$
Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're both active from $0$:$00$ to $6$:$00$ and $18$:$00$ to $24$:$00$, then if you pick a random time of day, the probability that they're both active is $\frac{1}{2}$ since they're simultaneously active for $12$ hours of the day.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you've just summed up the #time A and B are active and divided it to the number of block hours.

Comment: No, I summed up the number of blocks that they are $simultaneously$ active and divided it by the number of block hours.

Comment: But doing so seems a bit odd. Maybe my problem formulation needs some clarification :
If A = B = 1,1,00, the probability of them meeting should be 1 (since they are always awake at the same time) which doesn't seem to fit your formula.

Comment: I suppose I could be interpreting incorrectly, but I would say the probability is still $\frac{1}{2}$ in this scenario since they definitely won't meet from 12:00-24:00. However, if you're asking for the probability that they meet $given$ that at least one of them is active, then yes the probability is $1$ in that case.

Comment: I guess my problem is close to your last formulation. Given that at least one of them is active, what is the probability that they both meet at the same time. Can you give me the general formula in that case please?

Comment: That would be the number of blocks in which they are simultaneously active divided by the number of blocks in which at least one of them is active. In your original question, that probability would be $\frac{2}{3}$